# onclick of button from paginated load not triggering

Tags: javascript

I have a procedural feed within my website which loads in data every time the user scrolls to the bottom of the page; the usual stuff.

The pagination itself works fine; however, the clicking of buttons which utilize **JavaScript** do not work. At all.

This is the **JavaScript** trigger for the buttons which is not working:

```
var modalTrigger = document.querySelectorAll(".ts-modal__trigger"), // the buttons
    modal;

document.onclick = function(e){ // document on click
    for(var i = 0; i < modalTrigger.length; i++){ // iterate through each button
        if(e.target == modalTrigger[i]){ // if target clicked was button
            e.stopPropagation(); // stop dom event from bubbling
            modal = document.getElementById(modalTrigger[i].getAttribute("data-activemodal"));

            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; // disable scroll on page
            modal.style.display = "block"; // display modal
        }
    }   
}
```

As far as I'm aware, this **should** be working (with the use of `stopPropagation()`), but alas, it does not.

I was *going* to use **Inline JS**, but I feel like it's extremely unnecessary and could be done it just a couple of lines of separate **JavaScript**, instead of adding extra **HTML** into the mix for no reason.

So any, and all help is appreciated,

Thanks. :)

Fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/xhp4cesr/**

**EDIT:** I noticed that after removing the `span` within the button, it would work, but as soon as it was added back, it would not.

Comment: If you calling this `document.querySelectorAll(".ts-modal__trigger")` on document load, then it won't select the the elements which got loaded later by ajax.

Comment: Not sure if that's how it works, dude. Pretty sure it checks with the `for` loop, on `document` click. But, I could be wrong :) post an answer if you think otherwise

Comment: why don't you try and move your `modalTrigger` declaration inside onclick function and see if that works.

Comment: Its working exactly as it should - click anywhere in the red box apart from the span and you get the console log - `e.stopPropagation();` stops it bubbling into the span

Comment: @DarrenSweeney how would I make sure it works on all the elements within too? :/

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to remove `e.stopPropogation` and also target the children

```js
var modalTrigger = document.querySelectorAll(".ts-modal__trigger"), // the buttons
  modal;

document.onclick = function(e) { // document on click
  for (var i = 0; i < modalTrigger.length; i++) { // iterate through each button
    if (e.target == modalTrigger[i] || modalTrigger[i].children) { /* <- added children as target */
      modal = modalTrigger[i].getAttribute("data-activemodal");
      console.log(modal);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  background: red;
  padding: 40px;
}

span {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a class="ts-modal__trigger" data-activemodal="ts-main-feed_status-comments-overlay">
  <span>11</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't it be `|| e.target == modalTrigger[i].children`? :)

Comment: Not needed - you're assigning either

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding the querySelector within the click handler :)

Comment: Ah, I've found a bug, whenever the user clicks ANYWHERE, it'll open the modal :/