# if statement running even if event.target is not the specified elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple `script` on my webpage which is supposed to open up a modal whenever a user clicks on a specific button on the page.

However, for some reason, even when the event target is not the specified elements, it will still trigger the modal open. Obviously, this is not supposed to happen, and I'm confused as to why it is.

Here is the **JavaScript**:

```
document.onclick = function(e){
    var modalTrigger = document.querySelectorAll(".ts-modal__trigger"),
        modals = document.querySelectorAll(".ts-modal"),
        i;

    for(i = 0; i < modalTrigger.length; i++){ 
        if(e.target == modalTrigger[i] || modalTrigger[i].children){
            modal = document.getElementById(modalTrigger[i].getAttribute("data-activemodal"));

            // these two will trigger not matter if the if statement is true
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; 
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the **HTML**:

```
<!-- trigger !-->
<a class="ts-modal__trigger" data-activemodal="ts-main-feed_status-comments-overlay">
    <span data-rot="11">11</span>
</a>
<!-- modal !-->
<div class="ts-modal" id="ts-main-feed_status-comments-overlay"></div>
```

All help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: The `||` operator doesn't work the way you seem to think it does. Do you want the if condition to test if the target is either the modal trigger or one of its children?

Comment: Or operator checks if any one of those condition is satisfied. Even if e.target is not defined but the second condition is true, the for loop will be executed.

Comment: @nnnnnn no, I knew it was like that. However, this guy stated it was alright to do so (http://stackoverflow.com/a/42872398/5859909), and if I changed it up to be correct, it would not work.

Comment: That answer is wrong. You can't test whether a value is one of several by using `||` like that.

Comment: @nnnnnn clearly hahahaha. Mind helping me out with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this line of your code:

```
if(e.target == modalTrigger[i] || modalTrigger[i].children)
```

Firstly the `||` does *not* work to test whether `e.target` is one of multiple possible values. The condition is evaluated like this:

```
(e.target == modalTrigger[i]) || modalTrigger[i].children
```

The second problem is that `modalTrigger[i].children` is a *list*. It will always be a truthy value in itself.

So your if condition is always true.

If you want to test whether `e.target` is either `modalTrigger[i]` or a descendant of `modalTrigger[i]` the way I would do it is to use the `.parentNode` property to navigate up from `e.target` to see if `modalTrigger[i]` is an ancestor:

```js
function containsChild(parent, child) {
  while (child != null) {
    if (parent === child) return true;
    child = child.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}

document.onclick = function(e){
    var modalTrigger = document.querySelectorAll(".ts-modal__trigger"),
        modals = document.querySelectorAll(".ts-modal"),
        i;

    for(i = 0; i < modalTrigger.length; i++){ 
        if(e.target == modalTrigger[i] || containsChild(modalTrigger[i], e.target)) {
            modal = document.getElementById(modalTrigger[i].getAttribute("data-activemodal"));
            // these two will trigger not matter if the if statement is true
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; 
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.ts-modal { display: none; }
```

```html
<!-- trigger !-->
<a class="ts-modal__trigger" data-activemodal="ts-main-feed_status-comments-overlay">
    <span data-rot="11">This is a span in a trigger element</span>
</a><br>
<a>This is not a trigger</a>
<!-- modal !-->
<div class="ts-modal" id="ts-main-feed_status-comments-overlay">This is the overlay</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou! +1 for really going in depth about what is wrong and how I could do it better :)